# Стоит ли создавать подклассы для вывода части от содержимого модели?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

Есть база данных номеров гостиницы. В ней содержится таблица со списком номеров. В таблице всякая информация о номере: описание, путь к фото, название, содержимое номера, цена, площадь и т.п.

На страницу сайта гостиницы со списком номеров выводится часть информации о номерах: их название, фото, описание, цена, площадь. Но есть страница с "подробным описанием номера". Там уже выводится много чего нового: всё что выводилось на странице со списком номеров, содержимое номера, все фото номера.

Всю инфу представляет одна модель `RoomModel`. Я слышал, что, если используется не вся информация, то нужно создавать другие модели, хранящие часть информации от модели `RoomModel`, чтобы не передавать лишние данные во View'шку.
Например, можно создать такие модели: `RoomDataCommon` и `RoomDataDetails`.

Стоит ли так делать или можно просто забить на эту идею/правило? Если нет, то чем помогает такое разделение вывода данных? Например: увеличивается скорость загрузки html-страницы, т.к. не надо передавать много данных, наглядно показывает, что и где будет выводится.

Comment: в данном случае можно использовать linq, а точнее его методы Skip и Take, и отображать на странице только нужное количество строк из таблицы.

Comment: @ДенисМатюшкин, это понятное дело, что можно всё "скипать". Вопрос в другом: как правильно с точки зрения архитектуры MVC?